# Knockout how to remove items from select dropdown if it is already selected in previous or next row

Tags: knockout.js

I have three rows here. First dropdown should displays all the names. If I select a name from the first dropdown, next dropdown should not contain the name selected in the first dropdown.

For eg. If I have {Peter,John,Michael}, first drop should show all three options. If I select Peter in the first dropdown, next row dropdown should only show {John,Michael}. If I select John in the second dropdown, final dropdown should only contain Michael.

```
<table>
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: Items">
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <select data-bind="options: $root.Persons, optionsText: 'name', event :{ change: $parent.SelectionChanged }" />
             </td>
           </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

i have made simple demo of what you what to do

```
function Person(firstName) {
    this.fname = firstName;
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.FirstSelectedPerson = ko.observable();
    self.FirstSelectPersons = ko.observableArray([
    new Person('Mark'),
    new Person('Peter'),
    new Person('Smith')]);
    self.SecondSelectedPerson = ko.observable();
    self.SecondSelectPersons = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.FirstSelectPersons(),

        function (person) {
            if (self.FirstSelectedPerson()) {
                if (person.fname.indexOf
                    (self.FirstSelectedPerson().fname) < 0) return true;
            }
        });
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

here is the full code **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/3w2Xq/)**

Comment: You have created first observable array with all the values, and second one is computed (by removing the first selection). It does work if every options are bound with separate observables. But for 5-6 options that are dynamically created and bound to same observableArray, is it possible to replicate the above functionality?

Answer (score -1):

You could use linq and a where clause to omit the entries that are already selected on postbacks.

Comment: Why do you think that C# is the backend? The question only mentions knockout which is a full client side library which can be used with any backends ruby, php, etc...

Comment: I have to do that using JavaScript on the client side, before postback, i.e. each row selection dropdown should have options already selected before.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the knockout tag.